# Windows 10 - Simulate keyboard delay

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse

Is there a software or any settings to simulate keyboard key strikes delay?

I tried keyboard settings repeat rate, but that only for holding and pressing a key.

But I want something like when I type a sentence very fast, characters should be slowly displaying on the screen.

One more thing I want do so is this:

Configure windows 10 to play sounds when switching/changing tabs for chrome and opera? Is there any addon or a software that can do that?

Comment: "Just a couple of milliseconds delay"? You would not be able to notice such a small delay.

Comment: is there any tool that I can test and increase or decrease delay?

Comment: Software and tool requests are off topic.

Comment: According to 3D Developer John Carmack, "Human sensory systems can detect very small relative delays in parts of the visual or, especially, audio fields, but when absolute delays are below approximately 20 milliseconds they are generally imperceptible."